# Logarithmic Y axis with GD::Graph

Tags: perl, charts, gd-graph

I am experiencing problems with plotting a logarithmic Y axis using the `GD::Graph` module.

I'm able to plot logarithmic values, simply by taking the logarithm of the data. I'm also able to print Y values back like this

```
y_number_format => \&y_exp_format,

sub y_exp_format {
    my ( $v ) = @_;
    return 0 if ! defined $v;
    return sprintf( "%.0f", exp($v-1));
}
```

But I have now exact exp($v-1) values as labels on my Y axis.

e.g.

[image]

Whilst I would like to see something like

[image]

Is it possible to solve this with `GD::Graph`, before grabbing another module?

Comment: @borodin. I see you edited/corrected my question, Thank you for that. I have one question though. Is it not allowed to mention the referenece to the user/website where I get the code/help from ? Just wanted to give credits to other perl-colleague and last but not least didn't want to pretend, the piece of code is mine. :)

Comment: It's not relevant to the question. This isn't the place to post thanks, and you don't claim to be the author of the code. You might add a link to the web page where you were given the advice.

Comment: @toolic I didn't  find anything about logarithm either, but I was hoping somebody did  something interresting in the subroutine providing input for y_exp_format.